# How to convert dataframe to a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

I have a dataframe that I would like to convert to ts and forecast the AvgWeight either starting on DOC 3 or SampleDate 2007-06-23. The AvgWeight is estimated weekly (DOC). I would like to forecast 3 weeks ahead of the last DOC (101) so I basically want predictions for DOC 108, 115, and 122. Could someone in this list help me to forecast this small dataset below?

```
      DOC AvgWeight PondName SampleDate
  1    3  1.000000   Pond01 2007-06-23
  2   10  1.666667   Pond01 2007-06-30
  3   17  2.066667   Pond01 2007-07-07
  4   24  2.275000   Pond01 2007-07-14
  5   31  3.833333   Pond01 2007-07-21
  6   38  6.200000   Pond01 2007-07-28
  7   45  7.400000   Pond01 2007-08-04
  8   52  8.500000   Pond01 2007-08-11
  9   59 10.250000   Pond01 2007-08-18
  10  66 11.100000   Pond01 2007-08-25
  11  73 13.625000   Pond01 2007-09-01
  12  80 15.200000   Pond01 2007-09-08
  13  87 16.375000   Pond01 2007-09-15
  14  94 17.800000   Pond01 2007-09-22
  15 101 21.500000   Pond01 2007-09-29
```

Here is the dput of the dataset above to be copied to R

```
 wt <- structure(list(DOC = c(3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38, 45, 52, 59, 66, 
 73, 80, 87, 94, 101), AvgWeight = c(1, 1.66666666666667, 2.06666666666667, 
 2.275, 3.83333333333333, 6.2, 7.4, 8.5, 10.25, 11.1, 13.625, 
 15.2, 16.375, 17.8, 21.5), PondName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Pond01", class = 

"factor"),  SampleDate = structure(c(1182585600, 1183190400, 
1183795200, 1184400000, 1185004800, 1185609600, 1186214400, 1186819200, 
 1187424000, 1188028800, 1188633600, 1189238400, 1189843200, 
 1190448000, 1191052800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = 
c("DOC", "AvgWeight", "PondName", "SampleDate"), row.names = c(NA, 15L
 ), class = "data.frame")  

wt$SampleDate <- as.Date(wt$SampleDate)
 wt
```

I tried;

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
pond <- ts(wt$AvgWeight,start=3,frequency=52,end=101)
autoplot(pond)
```

But my ts call is off. I am reading about ts but can't grasp it yet. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

1. The time series intialization is off - the one below should work.
2. `ggplot2::autoplot` does not seem to be a function for plotting time series but plotting fitted models from `forecast`

Something like this works for me - updated after OP comment:

```
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
pond <- ts(wt$AvgWeight,start=c(2007, 25), frequency=52)
autoplot(forecast(auto.arima(pond)))
autoplot(forecast(ets(pond)))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it rather be `start= c(2007, 25)` for the 25th week of 2007? The third integer 23 seems to be ignored anyway

Comment: Had a sloppy look at the documentation - thanks for pointing out @Aurèle!

Comment: For my model I wanted to try ARIMA or HoltWinters and would like to make plots like this page: http://rpubs.com/sinhrks/basics or this one: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast7-ggplot2/. Both pages seem to use autoplot from ggplot2. Looking at the x axis how can I show my DOC values (3 to 101) plus my 3 predictions (108, 115, and 122)?

Comment: Thanks for that link - did not know there was a ggplot2 wrapper for the forecast package now. Learnt something!

Comment: Instead of using start=c(2007,25) could the start be an integer (DOC)? for example I would like to start at 3 and end at 101 every 7 days? I estimate AvgWeight every 7 days and now that I have 15 AvgWeights I would like to predict for 3 ahead of DOC 101. Hope is clear.

Comment: What are the other arguments to ts? I've experimenting and can't come up with weekly periods for the AvgWeight

Comment: Just in case someone is going through the same painful process, this is what I did. I was not able to find a way to create weekly breaks using ts() for my dataset, so I ended up mixing xts to create my weekly breaks and then used the forecast package to 'forecast' 3 weeks ahead.                                                                                               
 pond <- as.xts(wt$AvgWeight,order.by=seq(as.Date("2007-06-23"), by=7, len=15))

Comment: -I still would like to know how ts() breaks by week.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604432/daily-time-series-with-ts-how-to-specify-start-and-end